# showing text and image both while displaying list of applications in android

Tags: android

i want to create a home screen application where the applications looks like carousel , and i am able to do it . The problem i am facing is that in my application only the applications icon are getting displayed the text is missing in it , where as my requirement is that i want to both the icon and text to be displayed together. [image]

my application displays same as the above showing image. [image]

i want text to be combined with it as above image.

please help me.

Thanks 
datta

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code for us to look at? How you accomplishing the carousel in the first place?

Comment: @kurtis Nusbaum : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx i followed the above link , where i changed the code to get the application icons. If that is not sufficient then i put code where i changed the code to get the app icons..

Comment: You have to modify `CarouselImageView`

Comment: @adil . no i dint change carouselImageView , i changed carousel.java.

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest thing to do would be to create a [Compound Control](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound). This compound control would essentially be a LinearLayout with both and ImageView and a TextView in it. Then, where ever you use a CarouselImageView in your code, just use your new compound control instead.

Comment: What aren't you understanding?